# Get directory list from external file server using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I would like to get the list of directories from an external file server using ASP.net

Comment: Kindly elaborate your question more.

Comment: in c# we get the list of directories using the following codes.. DirectoryInfo di=new DirectoryInfo("c:\test);        But in asp.net this is not working! hope this should be clear!

Answer (score 0):

For listing files from network shared location you can use following code.

```
 string path= @"\\server\sharedfolder"; 
 DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
 FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles("*.*");
 foreach(FileInfo fi in files)
 {
  //Your code goes here      
 }
```

But, make sure that your ASP.NET web application has permissions on the shared folder.

Comment: Thanks @Monie..  I tried using the same code earlier.. but it says "Access to the path "\\server\sharedfolder" is dened".  Now hod can i ensure that the ASP.net web application has permissions on the shared folder.  Please help!

Comment: Did you host your application on IIS or browsing from VS?

Comment: IF you use IIS, Add IIS_IUSRS group to that folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Path.GetDirectoryName(path) method`

link  : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx

You can also use

`var result  = new FileInfo(path).Directory.FullPath`

Comment: but how do i set the permission in iis